# apache , php , sendmail not working

Tags: apache-2.2, php, sendmail

I am using apache, php and sendmail. I can send mail from command line with sendmail.

However, in php file, mail function is not working.

Then, I run that php email test file from command line. It works.

> #>php mail_test.php

I thought it is apache issue and I changed httpd_can_sendmail on. But it is still not working. I checked sendmail permission and it is 666.

I checked httpd error log and I found this:

> sh: /usr/sbin/sendmail: Permission denied.

I don't know where to change permission anymore.

Comment: What is the user:group of php/apache ?

Comment: The permission cannot be 666, for then the sendmail binary is not executable.

Comment: yes 777 now but not working yet Thanks . Error must be somewhere else

Comment: What do logs say now?

Comment: Still the error log 
[Fri Jan 27 06:25:23 2012] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Fri Jan 27 06:25:23 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Jan 27 06:25:28 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication .
[Fri Jan 27 06:25:28 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Jan 27 06:25:29 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips SVN/1.6.11 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
sh: /usr/sbin/sendmail: Permission denied

Comment: Try chmod -v 2755 /usr/sbin/sendmail. Also do you have any symlinks to this?

Comment: Btw what are you using as a mail agent? When I used mail() in PHP to pass mail to Postfix, I found out that it ignored SMTP settings completely and passed the mail of to the `pickup` daemon. So if you have not handled pickup in your `master.cf` file, well ... you won't be able to send mail.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/SendMail/Q_23342902.html) (look at the bottom) suggests that it may be a problem with SELinux permissions. Do you have [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux) enabled?

Comment: Thanks ,It was. Now I changed it to SELinux disabled . But Still no luck.